# What is causing this compile error?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the following function that counts the time  have a "X" value in certain cells.

```
 Sub CountVars()

  Dim r As range, count As Long

   For Each r In range("C3", "F3", "H3")
   If r.Value = "X" Then count = count + 1
   Next

  End Sub
```

When I run the function I get an error however highlighting " Sub CountVars()". Is says

```
"Compile error: wrong number of arguments or invalid property assingment".
```

Already tried to google but cant find out where the error is coming from. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try it as,

```
Sub CountVars()
    Dim r As range, count As Long
    For Each r In range("C3, F3, H3")
        If r.Value = "X" Then count = count + 1
    Next
End Sub

Alternately as,

Sub CountVars2()
    Dim r As range, count As Long
    For Each r In Union(range("C3"), range("F3"), range("H3"))
        If r.Value = "X" Then count = count + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

The [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) can take a union of cells addresses in as a text string but only in one piece.